# Script to install Debian has UEFI issues, acts inconsistently across machines

Tags: bash, debian, arch-linux, uefi, debootstrap

For my own personal purposes, I am writing a script in order to automate installation of a custom Debian system onto the hard drive of whatever computer the script is running on. This script is intended to be used from any live Linux distribution.

I am aware of Debian preseeding - unfortunately, preseeding is not a viable solution in this situation.

The script works. However, it does not work consistently. On some machines (for example, my 2011 Macbook Air), the new EFI configuration is updated without any issues. However, on some machines (notably newer Dell laptops), I have to go into the BIOS and manually add my `\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi` file.

How would I alter the below script in order to accommodate most modern UEFI systems?

I am aware that I will likely need to alter my `efibootmgr` commands below.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Preliminary commands
set -e

echo "Available disks:"

current_disk=$(df / | awk 'NR==2 {print $1}')
for disk in $(lsblk -dnro NAME,TYPE | awk '$2=="disk" {print $1}'); do
if [ "$disk" != "${current_disk#/dev/}" ]; then
    size=$(lsblk -dnro SIZE "/dev/$disk")
    echo "/dev/$disk: $size"
fi
done

read -p "Enter the disk you want to install Debian on (e.g. /dev/sda): " disk

mkdir -p /mnt
sgdisk --zap-all "$disk" > /dev/null
parted "$disk" mklabel gpt
parted "$disk" mkpart ESP fat32 0% 512MB
parted "$disk" mkpart primary ext4 512MB 100%

# Set up main partition
yes | mkfs.ext4 "${disk}2"
mount "${disk}2" /mnt

# Set up EFI partition
yes | mkfs.fat -F32 "${disk}1"
mkdir -p /mnt/efi
mount "${disk}1" /mnt/efi

debootstrap --arch=amd64 buster /mnt http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/

# Set up bindings
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

# Chroot to set up grub
chroot /mnt /bin/bash << "EOT"
apt update -y
apt install -y linux-image-amd64 grub-efi-amd64
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id=debian --recheck --no-floppy
update-grub
EOT

# Set the path to your .EFI file
efi_file="\EFI\debian\grubx64.efi"
bootnum=$(efibootmgr -v | grep "Boot" | awk '{print $1}' | sed 's/Boot//g' | sort -n | tail -1 | awk '{print $1+1}')
efibootmgr -c -d "$disk" -p 1 -L "Debian" -l "${efi_file}" -b "${bootnum}"
efibootmgr -o "${bootnum}"

# Unmount bindings
umount -l /mnt/sys
umount -l /mnt/proc
umount -l /mnt/dev

# Unmount filesystems
umount -l /mnt/efi
umount -l /mnt

reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

Newer systems tend to have Secure Boot enabled by default, and `grubx64.efi` needs to be explicitly whitelisted if you want to boot it directly in systems with factory default configuration, as Debian's `grubx64.efi` is not signed by either Microsoft or the system manufacturer.

When you go to BIOS settings and manually configure `grubx64.efi` to boot, the firmware might automatically whitelist it for you, as you have explicitly specified you wish to use it, in a direct user interaction that cannot be (easily) subverted by software.

You should probably change the line

```
apt install -y linux-image-amd64 grub-efi-amd64
```

to

```
apt install -y linux-image-amd64 grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-signed shim-signed
```

This will install a version of `grubx64.efi` that has all relevant GRUB modules built-in (since Secure Boot will prevent GRUB from loading any modules: GRUB modules are not PE-COFF binaries but ELF binaries, so the Secure Boot firmware cannot validate them) which is signed by Debian, and `shimx64.efi` which is signed by Microsoft. Both of those have been built as reproducible binaries, so if you wish, you can redo the build process yourself to get absolutely identical binaries, so you can verify there is no malware in their code.

If the `-signed` packages are installed, `grub-install` should automatically use them, but if you want to be sure, you can add the `--uefi-secure-boot` option for it to specify you explicitly want to use them.

When used in this way, you should change `efi_file=` to be `\EFI\debian\shimx64.efi`; it will check for Secure Boot, non-persistently add Debian's Secure Boot certificate to the whitelist if necessary, and then load `grubx64.efi` automatically. If the system has Secure Boot disabled, it will just load `grubx64.efi` and run it.